# In DirectX 11, how to create and register two buffers in SwapChain (DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC)

Tags: directx, buffer, directx-11, direct3d11

I am a beginner of DirectX 11, and following the book Beginning DirectX 11, in chapter 2, there is a code for creating a buffer using the following code:

```
DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC swapChainDesc;
ZeroMemory( &swapChainDesc, sizeof( swapChainDesc ) );
swapChainDesc.BufferCount = 1;
swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Width = width;
swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Height = height;
swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 60;
swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
swapChainDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
swapChainDesc.OutputWindow = hwnd;
swapChainDesc.Windowed = true;
swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
```

My question is that in the [description of swap chain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb173075%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), apparently there is space for only one buffer, as there is only one BufferDesc (DXGI_MODE_DESC struct). So if BufferCount is set to 2 or more, how is the second buffer registered? Is it using another DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC? Please post some example code.

Also BufferCount has type UNIT, which means more than two buffers can be added. While 2 buffers are used in double buffering technique, in which one buffer is used to draw on, and another buffer is used to display on the scene, and buffers are swapped. What is the use, advantages of more than two buffers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having more buffers generally means a speed improvement. When the buffers are swapping, you can't do any rendering on any of them. You have to wait until they are fully swapped. This could take some time which you could have used rendering another frame. Triple buffering is exactly this. You can go up to 4 (6?) buffers, when doing some stereoscopic stuff. Any more would be useless.

Haven't got my hands on DX for a while, but I remember it handling it automatically when swapChainDesc.BufferCount is set to a value. Also, I know this is only chapter two, but please, use two buffers. No matter what they say, your code won't change, and you'll have a speed increase .And anyways, it is better to have two buffers. What if your one and only buffer can't be fully rendered on the next VBlank ? Oops, missing image.

Comment: "You can go up to 4 (6?) buffers" - where are you taking these numbers from?

Comment: @rursw1: Having more than 4 buffers usually results in worse performance and terrible input lag. So, it should be "it is recommended not to go over 4 buffers, but you totally can if you want".